# XML Namespace retrieving sub-elements in foreach loop

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have the XML code below. I am using namespace to retrieve the 'api' values which is working successfully when getting them individually but when I try to retrieve 2 fields within the same foreach I just get array values.

```
<entry>
<id>tag:elements</id>
<category scheme="http://test.com" term="item" label="Item" />
<updated>2023-07-16T10:50:49.573+01:00</updated>
<link type="application/atom+xml" rel="alternate" href="https://test.com" />
<title>SOMEONE</title><content type="xhtml">
<api:object category="user" id="1234">
    <api:ever-approved>true</api:ever-approved>
    <api:privacy-level>Public</api:privacy-level>
    <api:privacy-level-locked>false</api:privacy-level-locked>
    <api:is-public>true</api:is-public>
    <api:allow-type-switching>true</api:allow-type-switching>
    <api:is-current-staff>true</api:is-current-staff>
    <api:is-login-allowed>true</api:is-login-allowed>
    <api:title>Ms</api:title>
    <api:initials>S</api:initials>
    <api:last-name>SOMEONE</api:last-name>
    <api:first-name>ME</api:first-name>
    <api:email-address>test@test.com</api:email-address>
    <api:primary-group-descriptor>DEPARTMENT</api:primary-group-descriptor>
    <api:user-identifier-associations user-id="1234">
    <api:user-identifier-association scheme="email-address" status="claimed" decision="always-me">test@test.com</api:user-identifier-association>
</api:object>
</entry>
```

This works to retrieve fields individually:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('mypeople.xml', NULL, NULL, 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('api', 'http://www.test.com/publications/api');
foreach($xml->xpath('//api:object/api:email-address') as $header)
{
echo $header;
}

foreach($xml->xpath('//api:object/api:user-identifier-associations/@user-id') as $xd_item)
{
echo $xd_item;

}
```

But when I try something like the below in a loop it fails (I have tried re-registering the namespace to $entry but this hasnt helped.

```
foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
$entry->registerXPathNamespace('api', 'http://www.test.com/publications/api');
echo($entry->xpath('//api:object/api:email-address'));
echo($entry->xpath('//api:object/api:user-identifier-associations/@user-id'));
}
```

Comment: Calling `xpath` will always return an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not set variables for each of the values you need?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('mypeople.xml', NULL, NULL, 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('api', 'http://www.test.com/publications/api');

foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
    $entry->registerXPathNamespace('api', 'http://www.test.com/publications/api');

    // Grab the values
    $emailAddress = (string)$entry->xpath('//api:object/api:email-address')[0];
    $userId = (string)$entry->xpath('//api:object/api:user-identifier-associations/@user-id')[0];

    // Now you can use them as needed
    echo "Email Address: " . $emailAddress . "\n";
    echo "User ID: " . $userId . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi James, many thanks for this. Its close but for some reason it is stuck displaying the first record only. It returns the correct number of records but they are all the same.

Comment: So just had to add a counter..

Comment: $counter = 0;
foreach ($xml->xpath('//api:object') as $entry) {
 
    $emailAddress = (string)$entry->xpath('//api:object/api:email-address')[$counter];
    $userId = (string)$entry->xpath('//api:object/api:user-identifier-associations/@user-id')[$counter];

    // Now you can use them as needed
    echo "Email Address: " . $emailAddress . "\n";
    echo "User ID: " . $userId . "<br>";
 
 $counter++;
}